# Design pattern to evaluate a boolean expression

Tags: string, design-patterns

Is there a common/defined design pattern which will help program an evaluator for boolean expressions.

I am writing a string matching algorithm for such expressions and looking for a design pattern which will help structure the algorithm.

Sample Expected Strings -

```
"nike AND (tshirt OR jerseys OR jersey OR tshirts OR (t AND shirt)) AND black"
```

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Comment: You need a parser or regular expression, not a design pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is in the [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation). To evaluate it, convert it to the [postfix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Infix expression looks like:

```
<operand><operator><operand>
```

Postfix expression looks like:

```
<operand><operand><operator>
```

You can convert your expression using [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

As the expression is converted, [evaluate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Evaluate-Postfix-Expression) it using this approach (pseudocode):

```
Begin
   for each character ch in the postfix expression, do
      if ch is an operator ⨀ , then
         a := pop first element from stack
         b := pop second element from the stack
         res := b ⨀ a
         push res into the stack
      else if ch is an operand, then
         add ch into the stack
   done
   return element of stack top
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a design pattern per se which would fit your problem, but if your programming language has regex support, we can easily enough write a pattern such as this:

```
(?=.*\bnike\b)(?=.*\b(?:tshirts?|jerseys?|t\b.*\bshirt|shirt\b.*\bt))(?=.*\bblack\b).*
```

The pattern can be explained as:

```
(?=.*\bnike\b)   match "nike" AND

(?=.*\b(?:tshirts?|jerseys?|t\b.*\bshirt|shirt\b.*\bt))
    match tshirt(s), jersey(s) or "t" and "shirt" AND

(?=.*\bblack\b)  match "black"

.*               then consume the entire line
```

### Demo